# close fragment and activity B at the same time (go back to activity A)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an application with specific architecture regarding navigation. The situation I have right now is like this:

I have activity A. My activity opens activity B with function startActivityForResult().
After that on activity B is added fragment X.

Right now I am on fragment X and I detected the close button click and I transferred this event to activity B. Now I want to go back to activity A. The only way I see at this moment to achieve this is by calling 2 times function onBackPressed() in a row. This creates laggy animation in which the user sees removing of fragment and activity B in delay. This is bad for UX and looks bad in code.

Does anyone have some better suggestions?

Comment: Just call finish() on Activity B one time. You should never be calling onBackPressed(). It can lead to finicky behavior. The functions starting with “on” are for the framework to call.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are right this works. If you want answer it and I will accept. But regarding never using functions starting with “on”? I saw this in practically every app I worked on. Usually in the way that we override for exampe onBackPressed method, we change it a little bit and use it. Are you really sure this is bad? I would literally have problems with solving some specific cases/scenarios if I don't use any of these :O

Comment: It's perfectly fine to override `onBackPressed`, `onCreate`, etc. That's what you're supposed to do. What you're not supposed to do is *call* these functions directly. If you have reusable logic in your `onBackPressed()`, I would break it out into a separate function and call that function from inside your override of `onBackPressed()`. Calling `onBackPressed()` yourself can have weird side effects that may or may not change for different versions of Android or the Jetpack libraries, so it's best to avoid doing that.

Comment: @Tenfour04 sure mate then everything is fine, it's just misunderstood. When I wrote in Q that I use onBackPressed() I meant on overridden onBackPressed with additional logic for going back. Didn't want to bother with additional info. But yea, maybe I should also write it in question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

on your fragment X button click.

> button.setOnClickListener{  (activity as ActivityB).finish() }

or

> button.setOnClickListener{ requireActivity.finish() }